# Avoid new Random for each instance schenanigans

Tags: java, constructor

Trying to get this code off the ground:

```
    Random random = new Random();
```

```
public Particle(int mouseInputX, int mouseInputY, int[] RGBBounds){
    this(mouseInputX, mouseInputY, 6, 12+ random.nextInt(10),RGBBounds);
```

But netbeans espouses that I can't reference random before the superclass constructor has been called. So I tried this:

```
        this(mouseInputX, mouseInputY, 6, 12+ new Random().nextInt(),RGBBounds);
```

Which works, but I don't want to create a new Random object for each particle object made (performance is already an issue). How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either way you are creating a new `Random()` object for each instance.

If you don't want to, you can make it `static`. But consider thread-safety. Take a look at [this article by Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2005/12/02/77520.aspx) (plus the comments below)

Answer (score 1):

You can make it static and provide a static synchronized method to access it.

Comment: Static's the way to go. Thanks playa.

Comment: Just make it final too and then you don't need the synchronized.